# Android/Jsch - SSH Output always empty

Tags: android, ssh, output, bufferedreader, jsch

I have the exact same problem described here:
[SSH Output always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863297/ssh-output-always-empty)

Unfortunately the accepted answer doesn't work for me, because

```
bufferedReader.readLine()
```

ends up in a loop, probably because of the missing end of line.

In addition I don't get why the code in the first posting doesn't work.
Anyone with a deeper insight?

thx in advance

EDIT: if i do

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
    stringBuilder.append('\n');
}
```

AFTER the ssh connection is closed, there is no endless loop, but the output is still empty...

```
stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.read());
```

leads to -1 as output.

just:

```
stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.readLine());
```

results in "null".

what is this madness? i don't get it...

Answer (score 2):

Answer: I was reading the wrong stream AND had to close the connection afterwards.

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
session.setPassword(password);

// Avoid asking for key confirmation
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(prop);

session.connect();

// SSH Channel
ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)
session.openChannel("exec");
InputStream inputStream = channelssh.getInputStream(); 

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line;

/**/
// Execute command
channelssh.setCommand(command);
channelssh.connect();

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
    stringBuilder.append('\n');
}

channelssh.disconnect();

return stringBuilder.toString();
```